# What is absolute symbol and how to define it in C?

Tags: c, linker, ld, linker-scripts, relocation

In the man page of `nm`. It says

> “A” The symbol's value is absolute, and will not be changed by further linking.

However, I don't know what that means. How can I define a variable or something else to make its value absolute **in C**?

If I declare a variable in `test.c` in its file scope

```
int a;
```

Then in the output of `nm`, the entry for a will be the following on my machine

```
0000000000000004 C a
```

So I'm wondering what can I do to make the `nm` output “A” for a variable. And I don't know what “absolute” means.

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29110226/1627113) may be of interest.

Comment: @Lefteris Thank you for the comment. I've read that post already. However, the answer says I need to use linker script to do it. Do you know if there's any way I can do it without linker script?

Comment: Because the C standard does not even mentin absolute or relative symbols. This is a matter of the environment.

Comment: You have to use a linker script anyway. What is your actual issue?

Comment: @Olaf Sorry I don't know the problem is actually not about C. I just want to know how can I achieve it in plain C code, without the help of linker script. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Did you eve read my previous comments? You cannot!

Comment: @Olaf Saying you cannot do this C is like saying you cannot implement a binary tree in C because C standard does not mention it either.

Comment: @KenKenKen: Unrelated != cannot! After almost 2 years you really should know what I meant. It still is not related to C and your question is not clear either. Feel free to provide a reference to the C standard (there is none). The accepted answer makes this clear. If you did not understand it, why do you accept it?

Comment: @Olaf I agree that "Unrelated != cannot". However, you first said "This is not related to C", then you said "You cannot!". Do you see the contradiction here?

Comment: @KenKenKen: Yes, because this is not part of the C standard. Maybe I should have been more specific, but I assume it was clear from the context.

Comment: @Olaf Yes I know it's not related to C standard, but this fact does not make the question unrelated to C. If I asked a question about how to implement something in C, then that is related to C because how it's done in C will be different from how it's done in other languages. If I was just asking about the concept of absolute symbol or binary tree, then sure it's not related to C at all. Do you see my point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When C compiler compiles your program, it produces a list of symbols in addition to the binary code of your program. The most common types that you are going to see are `U`s (for "undefined"), `D`s and `S`s (for global data), and `T`s (for "text" segment, which is where the executable code goes).

`A`s, or *absolute* (un-moveable) symbols are there to support embedded development, where placement of things at absolute addresses in memory is required. Normally you would produce such symbols only when cross-compiling for an embedded system, using C language extensions that let you specify the absolute address. A typical syntax would look like this:

```
unsigned char buf[128]@0x2000;
```

This is not a standard C, though, it's an extension for embedded systems. The code like this would produce an absolute symbol `buf` set at address `0x2000`, which cannot be moved by linker.

Comment: This is compiker-specific. Not even every embedded compiler will accept this. And objects with absolute addresses will likely have to be `volatile`, too.

Comment: @Olaf Absolutely correct, that's not even close to being standard. That's why I wrote "C language extension".

Comment: "... , it's an extension for embedded systems" Sound like it is standard for embedded systems, so such compilers will support this. That's why I commented. Strange as it sounds, just properly casting an integer constant is often the more "portable" way (considering we are outside of the standard anyway).

Comment: Note that dos commonly used this too. keyboard access and textmode video buffer access (for more than simple line based usage) commonly used such variables.

Comment: Which C compilers support this extension with that syntax? Some compilers support the feature but using syntax which is less non-standard, for example see `__attribute__((at(0x40001000)))` supported by RealView ARM C compiler – https://stackoverflow.com/q/4067811

Comment: @SimonKissane Take a look at [this article](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/11/01/defining-variables-at-absolute-addresses-with-gcc/) for info on this and other ways of doing it.